Trying to use a for loop in Python that outputs the bigger than or equal to numbers in the sequence
Here's my code from Python:
largest_so_far = -1
print('before', largest_so_far)
for the_num in [9, 41, 12, 3, 74, 15] :
    if the_num > largest_so_far :
        largest_so_far = the_num
    print(largest_so_far, 'is bigger than', the_num)
    if the_num == largest_so_far :
        largest_so_far = the_num
    print(the_num, 'is equal to', the_num)

print(largest_so_far, 'is the largest number!')

But it always output this in cmd (using cmd to run my .py files):
before -1
9 is bigger than 9
9 is equal to 9
41 is bigger than 41
41 is equal to 41
41 is bigger than 12
12 is equal to 12
41 is bigger than 3
3 is equal to 3
74 is bigger than 74
74 is equal to 74
74 is bigger than 15
15 is equal to 15
74 is the largest number!
How can I get it to just show the correct numbers?
tried replacing the > for is or is not operators but no go.

You forgot to indent your print statements. Also, What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?

Your logic is mostly correct but there are small implementation mistakes:

You have not indented the print statements. Indenting them would make sure they are executed only when the conditional block is run.
You are printing the values after updating the largest_so_far variable, so you lose the older value that you want to print.

Below is the code which fixes both issues.
largest_so_far = -1
print('before', largest_so_far)
for the_num in [9, 41, 12, 3, 74, 15] :
    if the_num > largest_so_far :
        print(the_num, ' is bigger than ', largest_so_far)
        largest_so_far = the_num
    elif the_num == largest_so_far :
        print(the_num, 'is equal to', largest_so_far)
        largest_so_far = the_num
print(largest_so_far, 'is the largest number!')


Thank you for the response. I should have been more thorough with my question. I wanted to get rid of the incorrect answers and replace them with the right answers like converting 74 is bigger than 74 to 74 is equal to 74.

@Blightsun, did my answer resolve the problem you were facing?
